# How to convert "EPIC" 4E Solo monsters to 5E?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-4e, dungeons-and-dragons, conversion

I've been scouring the web to find a good example of converting D&D 4E EPIC monsters (level 20-35+ in 4E) to equivalent 5E versions. I did see a couple of threads here and they help with how to conceptually do it, but I'd love to see a basic stats/saves/AC/HP/CR (level) conversion of say... Orcus or some diety, etc.

I did check out the [Improved Monster Stats](https://songoftheblade.wordpress.com/2015/09/09/improved-monster-stats-table-for-dd-5th-edition/) blog post and the table he worked out seems good. I also know I could go find an equivalent CR creature in 5E MM/Volos/Foes books and build from that, grafting the 4E powers I like to the 5E simulacra. That's all good.

But I'm stuck on this: How do 4E creature levels map to 5E from 1-35+? More specifically, What is the 5E CR/Level of a level 35 4E creature, or a even a level 20 4E creature for that matter?

Looking for good, consistent ideas to port some faves from 4E over to 5E.

Thanks in advance for the help!
KP

Comment: For what it's worth, Orcus appears in Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes (I mention it since you listed it as an example).